# CSS Title Question

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to customise the CSS of a site I regularly use.

My question relates to a title tag of an element (below).

```
<span title="42%" class="progress"><span style="width: 42%;" class="indicator">
</span></span>
```

I'd like to take this title tag (42% in this case, but changing dynamically) and display it as text using CSS.

The tricky part obviously comes from the fact that this unit changes dynamically.

Is there a way to say 'display the unit inside the title " " as text' using CSS.

Thanks in advance, all help appreciated.

Tom Perkins

Comment: Mixing content and design is a horrible practice, not to be encouraged, ever. The things you want are separate entities, originating from a single point, but should remain separated forever after... If you want to couple both, use javascript.

Comment: Can you explain more about your question? It is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean displaying the `title` attribute along with your existing text/elements instead of as a custom-designed tooltip, some browsers support the CSS `attr()` function:

```
.progress:after {
    content: attr(title);
}
```

See [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Ra5tU).

Comment: Interesting that CSS `content: attr()` even works dynamically. Just tried it out.

Comment: Of course, this is just an experiment, and I cannot guarantee support in all browsers especially IE.

Comment: Even if `attr()` is supported in IE, `:after` isn't, at least in IE6/7. I think it did make it into IE8, but you may still want to check it to be sure it works dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As said here:

http://groups.google.com/group/css-design/browse_thread/thread/3c3194dd0a3c7898

"The presentation of the title as a tooltip is a function of the 
browser and is not controlled by HTML or CCS. "

You can follow the links there to see some fixes for that

Comment: That's not what he was asking.